# Why do I need to specify schema for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent filters?

Tags: android

In my app, I'm trying to listen to broadcast intents with action `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`. But unless I also specify data schema `package`, my broadcast receiver doesn't ever get activated. Why do I need to specify the data schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Intent` that is broadcast has a `Uri`, and `Intent` resolution rules dictate that you must have a filter that matches the `Uri`.